# Jetty Version 9 throws java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError for Embedded Server

Tags: jetty, java-7, embedded-jetty

I decided to upgrade Jetty in order to add support for HTTPS connections. The build was done successfully by Maven and the code runs on Java 7 JRE.
After an upgrade from Jetty 8 (8.1.8.v20121106) to Jetty Version 9 (9.2.14.v20151106) using an embedded server code, I get the following error at the begin of the Jetty server startup.

Any hint what is causing the error at the classloader?

```
sh ./testit.sh
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConfiguration$Customizer
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verifyImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:94)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.prepare(J9VMInternals.java:514)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1113)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:507)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:499)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConfiguration$Customizer
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:600)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:777)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:750)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:326)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:731)
    ... 6 more
```

Comment: What's `J9VMInternals` ? sounds like you are using Java 9 or some other non Oracle JVM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've isolated the error cause. The Maven build tool added the Jetty distribution version number to the target libraries, which did not match my Java static classpath configuration. After correcting the classpath setting in the startup script, the program code started the embedded Jetty 9 server and worked just fine for my project.

@Joakim Erdfelt this is my Java version

```
java -version
java version "1.7.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build pxa6470sr9fp10-20150708_01(SR9 FP10))
IBM J9 VM (build 2.6, JRE 1.7.0 Linux amd64-64 Compressed References 20150701_255667 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - R26_Java726_SR9_20150701_0050_B255667
JIT  - tr.r11_20150626_95120.01
GC   - R26_Java726_SR9_20150701_0050_B255667_CMPRSS
J9CL - 20150701_255667)
JCL - 20150628_01 based on Oracle jdk7u85-b15
```